# how to access dictionary data from another class without using static variable in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am working on a .net core  project where i have to define dictionary in a class and fetch its value into another class.but i should not use static variable at the the time of  dictionary declaration....
here below is my code sample

```
Public classA{
public Dictionary<string, string> sample1{ get; set; }
public void method()
 {
 sample1= new Dictionary<string, string>();
 sample1.Add("Key", text);
}
}
```

and in another class

```
public classB
{
private classA _dataHelper;
public void getvalue()
{
string value = _dataHelper.sample1["Key"];
}
}
```

here in classB  the value im getting from Dictionary is null...how to solve this problem

Comment: Unless you're not initializing _dataHelper, which in the current sample you're not, the there's no problem. By initializing, I mean instantiating and calling method().

Comment: You never initialize your `_dataHelper` variable in `classB`, nor call `method()` on it.  I imagine this would be giving you a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: but i am declaring dictionary globally...

Comment: There's no such thing as "Globally", only static ... you are defining instance members in a non-static class which you have to instantiate...